# Run time error 5792- File name changes if word docx open

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

The macro is supposed to extract data from Docx files in a particular folder. If any of these folders are open when the macro is run, the program throws up an error 5792 and when I check the file name, the file name is changed partially. Why does it do that and how can I program around it.

File name is this: C:\Users\Ashley\Desktop\Victim Complaints\Victim Complaint Form.docx

When the docx is open and the macro is run, the file name changes to this and I get the error:
C:\Users\Ashley.Martin\Desktop\Victim Complaints\~$ctim Complaint Form.docx

The program appears to run through the actual files that are there, but then it will run an extra file with the corrupted file name.

```
Option Explicit


Dim FSO As Object
Dim myFile As Object
Dim myFolder As Object
Dim file As Object
Dim intRow As Integer
Dim docVic As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim strSumDoc As String
Dim LastSave As Date
Dim SumLastSave As Date
Dim docWord As Object
Dim appWord As Object
Dim FilePath As Variant
Dim HeadRange As Range

Sub VictimComplaints()


Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set myFolder = FSO.getfolder(ThisWorkbook.Path)
Set docVic = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application.16")
Set HeadRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:AT2")

appWord.Visible = False

 iCol = 1


'loops through filepaths in folder


For Each myFile In myFolder.Files
    LastSave = FileDateTime(myFile)
    If Right(myFile, 5) = ".docx" Then
        intRow = docVic.Cells(docVic.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        i = 3


        Do While i <= intRow
            strSumDoc = Cells(i, "B")
            SumLastSave = Cells(i, "C")
            'info on summary doc is already the latest bit of information
            If strSumDoc = myFile And LastSave <= SumLastSave Then
                 Exit Do

            'matching file already on document and saved later than last save date so info gets updated
            ElseIf strSumDoc = myFile And LastSave > SumLastSave Then
            '**Extracts data--works fine
                Exit Do

            'No match was found and at first empty row, make new entry on the summary doc
            ElseIf strSumDoc = "" Then
                'copy info to last row
                'MsgBox "Copy to last row " & myFile.Name
                strSumDoc = myFile  
                Set docWord = appWord.documents.Open(strSumDoc) '**Throws error because file name changed but there should be no file left.
                tblCount = docWord.tables.Count
                    With docWord
                    With .tables(1)
                    'Extracts data from table, works fine
                Exit Do

            Else:  'iteration doesn't match myfile, loop to next row
            End If

        i = i + 1
        Loop
        End If
Next

appWord.Quit
Set appWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/405257/what-type-of-file-is-file

Answer (score 0):

To program around it, I skipped filenames that started with the "~$". No clue why or how it finds that filename when looping through the files in the folder. There are no files named that in there. So this question is like half answered. I likely just bandaided over a bigger problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem with a slipstick.com macro to save an outlook item as docx. I had commented out "wrdDoc.Close" with an apostrophe as I was trying to get the docx to open and be tha active document, as I am trying to call 4 macros after each other. If I remove the apostrophe then the temp file with "tideS" disappears, and the macro works fine, the folder is not shared with anyone. Maybe if the file is not just created by a macro, you have to close down all the App versions for the doc type you want to open. Annoying, happened again not really sure with docx files. using [www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/can-vb-open-the-most-recently-created-file-in-a-folder.223730](http://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/can-vb-open-the-most-recently-created-file-in-a-folder.223730).  I changed line near end to: Documents.Open myDir & strFilename.      Just worked but not again. For myDir I added a backspace after the folder.